# How to prevent animation only on last child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-animations, opacity

I have a growing list of divs. The user can click a button to append a new div to the bottom.

This list has a fade-in animation, this is so that the user can see when the list has been loaded (it gets data from a server).

When a new row gets added, I’d like to not have the fade-in animation.

I tried using:

```
div:last-child {
  animation: none;
}
```

This works only the first time a new div has been added. On all the following additions, the animation gets applied regardless.

Please check this demo below to see what I mean:

```js
function addRow(text) {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.innerHTML = text;
  var root = document.querySelector('main');
  root.appendChild(d);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

main > div {
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid green;
  animation: fade-in 1s;
}

div:last-child {
  background: #999;
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from { opacity: 0 }
  to { opacity: 1 }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</main>
<button type="button" onclick="addRow('hello')">Add row</button>
```

How do I ensure the animation runs on the whole list the first time, but prevent it on subsequent additions?

Comment: *"How do I ensure the animation runs on the whole list the first time, but prevent it on subsequent additions?"* Which browsers/ minimal versions needs to be supported?

Comment: I need to support up to IE11 ideally, I don’t need to support mobile browsers

Comment: *"I need to support up to IE11 ideally"* as in IE6 to IE11 ? i hope not i assume you mean IE9 to IE11 there.

Comment: Thank god no :) I mean IE11 would be the oldest

Comment: Then iam pretty sure @AlvaroMontoro answer is what you are looking as it does not endanger browser support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option changing a little bit the JS and CSS:

1. Add a class to the newly added elements to the list

   ```
   d.className = "added";
   ```
2. Apply the animation only to the `div` that don't have that class

   ```
   main > div:not(.added) {
     animation: fade-in 1s;
   }
   ```

The initial `div` don't have that class, so they will be animated when the page loads, but the `div` that are added later (with the class name you specified) don't have any animation.

Here is a demo on how it would be based on your code:

```js
function addRow(text) {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.className = "added";
  d.innerHTML = text;
  var root = document.querySelector('main');
  root.appendChild(d);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

main > div {
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid green;  
}

main > div:not(.added) {
  animation: fade-in 1s;
}

div.added:last-child {
  background: #999;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from { opacity: 0 }
  to { opacity: 1 }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</main>
<button type="button" onclick="addRow('hello')">Add row</button>
```

Comment: Good solution as `:not()`  will not need other browser versions then `:last-child` (assuming the browser compatibility lists on the internet are correct) so it will not endanger browser support, so +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I ensure the animation runs on the whole list the first time

Simply apply it to the whole list

```js
function addRow(text) {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.innerHTML = text;
  var root = document.querySelector('main');
  root.appendChild(d);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

main > div {
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
main {
  animation: fade-in 1s;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from { opacity: 0 }
  to { opacity: 1 }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</main>
<button type="button" onclick="addRow('hello')">Add row</button>
```